# ".. what is the type and nature of job you are looking for." Why isn't "is" at the end?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence:

> First step is to decide what ***is*** the type and nature of job you are looking for.

([Source.](http://www.brokeinlondon.com/5-key-steps-get-job-london/))

I was expecting the second "is" to be at the end of the sentence instead of where it is.

Could anyone explain me this? Thanks!

Comment: Either way is fine. Could you add why you think it is wrong?

Comment: I thought the verb (second "is") always had to be after subject in affirmative sentences.

Comment: Think of it as: The first step is to decide (what is the type and nature of job you are looking for). Say the phrase with a pause after "decide" and it might make better sense.

Comment: @user39929 - In English, although there is no _rule_ prohibiting a writer from ending a sentence with "is," most writers make an effort to avoid doing so. This is a stylistic choice, because for some reason, sentences which end with _is_ "sound wrong" to some readers (and listeners.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the sentence may just lack some punctuation:

> First step is to decide: what is the type and nature of job you are looking for?

It might be that the author doesn't speak English fluently. The sentence has other errors, too:

- It's missing a definite article before *first*: "***The*** first step is..."
- It's missing a definite article before *job*: "*...the type and nature of **the** job you are looking for*"

There are other places in the article where the author omitted words or punctuation where I wouldn't consider it correct for words or punctuation to be omitted.

The author's phrasing isn't the best. I wouldn't expect the sentence to be written this way in a formal or professional document, but it probably wouldn't be too out of place in an informal conversation (where it is common for native speakers to knowingly make mistakes or use phrasings not used in formal English).

I would use one of the following phrasings:

> **The** first step is to decide what the type and nature of **the** job 
>   you are looking for **is**.
>
> **The** first step is to decide **the** type and nature of **the** job you
>   are looking for.

Contracting *you are* to *you're* is optional. Some people might pester you about [finishing a sentence with a preposition](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/), but they should be ignored.

Comment: ...ignored *to some extent.* I'd rather not encourage "What are you looking at?" or "That is the thing I'm in support of."

Comment: @LMS The missing _the_ before _job_ is not an error. It results from the omission of the article after "type of." This is perfectly common and acceptable, as in "What is the type and nature of job are you looking for?"

Comment: @Chowzen - That game is over, I'm afraid, and you are kicking field goals by moonlight.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I didn't say that we should hang those who hang prepositions, but  I still feel that some sentences that end with them sound low, debased. In my writing I often use phrases like my examples, but usually only when directly quoting a character. Outside of quotes I will rearrange my sentence to sound (to my ear) better: "That is the thing that I support." Let's not encourage people to tack prepositions onto every sentence, willy nilly, just because it's not something that *we'll get in trouble for*. That's the point *that I'm getting at*.

Comment: @Chowzen All true. My point, though, is that things like _What are you looking at?_ now sound just fine to the average English speaker (AES): neither low, nor debased, nor inferior in any way, stylistically or otherwise. In fact, the phrasing that you or I might find "better" now "sounds" affected to that AES, just as any use (even the _proper_ use) of the objective case of the pronoun _who_ now does. The time has long passed when our encouragement or discouragement might have made any difference. Thus _field goals my moonlight._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Understood. Yet I also understand that the English language evolves, and its evolution is derived in great part by what we, the entire English speaking population, say. So, I'll continue my encouragement and discouragement, doing my part as a "voter" to help steer the tongue clear of the treacherous teeth of linguistic mediocrity. "Keep holdin' 'em up, Lucy, and I'll keep *punting,* no matter the time of day."